# NodeJS - piping multiple FFMPEG processes

Tags: node.js, process, ffmpeg, pipe, converters

I am trying to programm an converter which can take any video source and convert it to mp3. The mp3 should be saved on my hard drive, or in an buffer to send it via telegram.

It works good so far, the only problem I am facing is that it can only take one video at a time, and I don't know why.

```
// IMPORTS
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var child_process = require('child_process');

// EVENTEMITER (Not used so far)
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;


// STREAMHANDLER
var StreamHandler = function(url, name){

    // VARIABLES
    self = this;
    this.url = url;
    this.name = name;

    // CREATE FFMPEG PROCESS
    var spawn = child_process.spawn;
    var args = ['-i', 'pipe:0', '-f', 'mp3', '-ac', '2', '-ab', '128k', '-acodec', 'libmp3lame', 'pipe:1'];
    this.ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', args);

    // GRAB STREAM
    https.get(url, function(res) {
        res.pipe(self.ffmpeg.stdin);
    });

    // WRITE TO FILE
    this.ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(name));

    //DEBUG
    this.ffmpeg.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
       console.error(self.name);
    });
}

util.inherits(StreamHandler, EventEmitter);


// TESTING
var test1 = new StreamHandler(vidUrl, "test1.mp3");
test1.ffmpeg.on("exit", function (code, name, signal) {
    console.log("Finished: " + test1.name);
});

var test2 = new StreamHandler(vidUrl, "test2.mp3");
test2.ffmpeg.on("exit", function (code, name, signal) {
    console.log("Finished: " + test2.name);
});
```

It skips test1.mp3 and only converts test2.mp3, but 2 ffmpeg processes were created:
[image]

After test2.mp3 is converted the other ffmpeg thread stays open, but does nothing, and the node program gets stuck waiting (i guess so) for it to send something.

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code, I had the same problem. It would hang at the end and only output data for the `test2.mp3` file. I'm not exactly sure what caused the problem, but I changed it a bit and this works for me:

```
// IMPORTS
var fs = require('fs');
//var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var child_process = require('child_process');

// EVENTEMITER (Not used so far)
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

// These never change...
var spawn = child_process.spawn;
var args = ['-i', 'pipe:0', '-f', 'mp3', '-ac', '2', '-ab', '128k', '-acodec', 'libmp3lame', 'pipe:1'];

// STREAMHANDLER
var StreamHandler = function(url, name){

    // CREATE FFMPEG PROCESS
    var ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', args);

    // GRAB STREAM
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        res.pipe(ffmpeg.stdin);
    });

    // WRITE TO FILE
    ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(name));

    ffmpeg.on("exit", function() {
        console.log("Finished:", name);
    });

    //DEBUG
    ffmpeg.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
       console.error(name, "received data");
    });
}
util.inherits(StreamHandler, EventEmitter);


// TESTING
var vidUrl = 'http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4';
var test1 = new StreamHandler(vidUrl, "test1.mp3");
var test2 = new StreamHandler(vidUrl, "test2.mp3");
```

I am using `http` instead of `https`, because I didn't have a sample video at an `https` url available. It shouldn't make a difference.

I moved the `spawn` and `args` variables out of the object, because they don't change. I also do not use `this` to store the local variables. I just use a normal closure instead. Finally, I moved the `exit` event handling code inside the object. I just think it's better to group all that stuff together -- plus, it's only declared once rather than for each new process you create.

Running this gives me the following output (I saved the script as `ffmpeg.js`):

```
$ node ffmpeg.js
test2.mp3 received data
Finished: test2.mp3
test1.mp3 received data
Finished: test1.mp3
```

Also, just a tip. If you want to use the `this` object inside `StreamHandler`, I would recommend using arrow functions if your version of Node supports them. This code also works:

```
var StreamHandler = function(url, name){

    // CREATE FFMPEG PROCESS
    this.ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', args);

    // GRAB STREAM
    http.get(url, (res) => {
        res.pipe(this.ffmpeg.stdin);
    });

    // WRITE TO FILE
    this.ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(name));

    this.ffmpeg.on("exit", () => {
        console.log("Finished:", name);
    });

    //DEBUG
    this.ffmpeg.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
       console.error(name, "received data");
    });
}
```

Notice that with arrow functions, I don't have to use `var self = this;` Avoiding that is pretty much the reason arrow functions were added to javascript.

Hope this helps!

**-- EDIT --**

Ok, I figured it out. The problem in your code is this line:

```
self = this;
```

It should be:

```
var self = this;
```

Without the `var` specifier, you are creating a global variable. So, the second time you are calling `new StreamHandler`, you are overwriting the `self` variable. That's why the `test1.mp3` file hangs and the `test2.mp3` file is the only one finishing. By adding `var`, your original script now works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Will look at it later. I really hope someone else knows why it doesn't work my way, so I can dodge this problem in the future

Comment: Do you know how to make those processes run in parallel? -> Please take a look at my new question :)